# Azure Storage file share mount point not showing files

Tags: linux, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to mount a file share on an Azure Storage account onto a linux VM.

The command I have issued is

```
sudo mount -t cifs //xxx.file.core.windows.net/xxx /home/vinay/idol-mount-new -o vers=3.0,username=xxxx,password=password==,dir_mode=7777,file_mode=7777
```

When list contents of idol-mount-new I see the following.

```
vinay@idol-linux:~/idol-mount-new$ ls -lart
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 8 vinay vinay 4096 Oct 18 01:47 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 vinay vinay 4096 Oct 18 01:47 .
vinay@idol-linux:~/idol-mount-new$ cd ..
```

Am i missing something.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Your VM OS is ubuntu, centos or others? which version? have you try this command `sudo mount -t cifs //<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<share-name> ./mymountpoint -o vers=2.1,username=<storage-account-name>,password=<storage-account-key>,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
`?

Answer (score 0):

**For Linux VM**: You need to create a local directory at **/mnt/mymountdirectory**, use the following example to create a local directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/mymountdirectory
```

Then Mount the SMB share to the local directory by providing your own storage account username and storage account key for the mount credentials as follows:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //myStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net/mystorageshare /mnt/mymountdirectory -o vers=3.0,username=mystorageaccount,password=mystorageaccountkey,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

For more details, refer “[Use Azure Files with Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux)”.